# Java writing outputted integers to file

Tags: java, binary, ascii

I need to generate 100,000 8 digit numbers and then write them to a file in Ascii and binary. I have the 100,000 8 digit numbers down... But I'm not sure where to start on converting them to Ascii and binary and writing them to a file. Any tips on getting the ball rolling here?

Comment: By "Ascii", do you mean "as text"?  Like `77256936` ?  And then binary, do you still mean "as text"? Like `100100110101101100011101000` ?

Comment: Don't mix ascii text and binary data in a single file (that's not going to work well).

Comment: Your problem description is close to nonsensical.  Are you talking about writing the data in "text" versus "binary"?  Are you talking about writing numbers in text as "decimal" (characters "0" through "9") versus "binary" (characters "0" and "1")?   Something else?  What you need to do is to carefully read the assignment you have been given and understand what it is actually asking you to do.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to use some form of a writer to write to a file. Example is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html).

You can also convert int to char to convert to Ascii.

```
int value = 98;
char digit = (char) value;
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your numbers are integers, to get the ASCII version of an integer, just cast it to a char:

```
int i = 65;
char ascii = (char) i;
```

To convert your integers to binary, you can use the `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)`  method:

```
int i = 65;
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(i);
```

As for writing to file, you could try using a `FileWriter` object:

```
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("numbers.txt")) {
    writer.write(ascii + "," + binaryString);
}
```